# pdo insert doesn't work if one textfiled is empty

Tags: php, pdo

I've posted my coding below. I'm trying to insert the datas into database. Problem is if user didn't select one textfield it does not insert the remaining datas into db. For example, i've a signup form. User should fill all the textfields, but userprofilepicture is optional. So, if user didn't choose his/her image file it doesn't insert the remaining datas. How to insert the datas if one textfield is empty?

```
if(isset($_POST['sub_values']))
{
    $c_uname = $_POST['uname'];
    // some codes
    // some codes
    // some codes
    $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

    if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) 
  { 
      $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];  

      $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
      $data = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
      $data = addslashes($data);
      fclose($fp);

        try
        {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ebusers (UserName, UserPassword, ConfirmPassword, FirstName, LastName, Address, UserEmail, UserPhone, Gender, UserProfilePicture, CreatedOn, isAdmin, UserSecretID) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, '$data', NOW(), ?, ? )");
            $conn->errorInfo();
            $stmt->bindParam('1', $c_uname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('2', $c_pwd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('3', $c_cpwd, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('4', $c_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('5', $c_lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('6', $c_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('7', $c_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('8', $c_phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('9', $c_fm, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('10', $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->bindParam('11', $token, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            'Error : ' .$e->getMessage();
        }
      }

        if($stmt)
        {
            echo "<script> alert('Registration successfully completed. You can login now'); </script>";
            echo "<script> location.href='index.php' </script>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script> alert('Registration Unsuccessfull. Try again or contact your administrator'); </script>";
            echo "<script> location.href='createuser.php' </script>";
        }

}
```

**Table Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ebusers` (
  `UserID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserName` char(25) NOT NULL,
  `UserPassword` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ConfirmPassword` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `UserEmail` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `UserPhone` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Gender` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `UserProfilePicture` longblob NOT NULL,
  `UserSecretID` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `ActiveStatus` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL,
  `CreatedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ModifiedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `isAdmin` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL,
  `UserToken` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`UserID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UserName` (`UserName`,`UserEmail`,`UserPhone`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=17 ;
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `bindValue()` instead? Also can you please paste the database table structure (eg are your optional fields allow null)

Comment: @Scuzzy : i've posted my table structure of this code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert statement is inside the following block:

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0)
```

Meaning, if that is NOT set, it will never run the insert statements.

I would update the code to something like this:

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']) && $_FILES['image']['size'] > 0) { 
    //do your stuff in here
    //etc etc
    $data = addslashes($data);
} else {
    $data = NULL;
}
```

Then run your insert statement after that.

Comment: you can see the remaining two in values `$data`, `NOW()`

Comment: How is $data declared?

Comment: $data is a image. i tried using `bindParam(':data', $data, PDO:PARAM_LOB)` to pass it. but it doesn't work. so, i passed it directly into the values.

Comment: i've modified table using this `ALTER TABLE ebusers MODIFY UserProfilePicture longblob null;` . but its not working..

Comment: You can also try to set that field to DEFAULT NULL so it will set it to NULL if no value is passed. It would be helpful if you posted the code around $data, as well as the exact error message you are getting back.

Comment: i've update my codes($data) in question. i've also used `ini_set('dispaly_errors', 1) error_reporting(E_ALL);` to get error. but, i didn't get any error...

Comment: If you are not getting an error, what behaviour are you getting? Nothing happens? I would set $data = ''; before your if isset $_FILES statement, as it looks like you are not setting $data to anything if !isset($_FILES).

Comment: Updated my answer again, if the code you pasted is accurate it looks like that is the problem.